Alter table name to another table name with AWS EMR and S3
Using EMR 7.2
spark-sql (default)> ALTER TABLE account RENAME TO accountinfo;
24/08/14 02:31:04 WARN SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Table rename is not supported
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Table rename is not supported


It seems that the version of Spark you're using on your EMR cluster does not allow table renaming in Hive metastore when the tables are stored in S3. This limitation is observed in specific versions of Spark and Hive.
I will give some possible solutions,
Solution 1: Create a new table
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE accountinfo LIKE account LOCATION '<existing_s3_path>';
DROP TABLE account;

or you can use CTAS
CREATE TABLE accountinfo AS SELECT * FROM account;
DROP TABLE account;

Solution 2: Rename in S3 and update table definition
ALTER TABLE account SET LOCATION 's3://new-path/accountinfo';

